# After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, top bars of apps are showing boxes with numbers in them instead of titles

Tags: upgrade, window, unicode, titlebar

Every application window has these numerical things instead of titles since I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04:

[image: boxes instead of a title]